# Add a text to input type image

Tags: html, css

I am using an input type image inside a div container. The image is a button. I would like to add text to this image in the center from the indentation of Left to Right. I am unable to get around it. Is the text hidden behind the image or is not at all getting displayed?

```css
  .container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
  }

  .container>* {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }


  .button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="image" class="button submit" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="submit" value="This is my text"/>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is your intent here? There's `input` type `file` for uploading any file based inputs.

Comment: The value field is the data that gets submitted to the form that the input would be part of, it will not be visible on the front end. What is your rationale for using an `input[type="image"]`? Explain your why.

Comment: When i use button, the size changes completely of the image that I am using. But when I use input, it automatically gets the right width and height.

Comment: The reason why the text is not appearing is because the browser ignores it. Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image  It states the value attribute should not be set.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar structure using an `img` tag as a background with `object-fit` to make it cover the entire element AND a inner `div` positioned in front of the `img` and using `display: flex;` to center the content of the inner div.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  color: red;
}

.container__image,
.container__inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container__image {
  object-fit: cover;
}

.container__inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="container__image" src="https://picsum.photos/800" alt="image placeholder"/>
  <div class="container__inner">
    <p>This is my text.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks! That is awesome to use flex. How do I make the text from left to right?

Comment: Just remove `justify-content`; you’ll probably want to add `padding` too